# Keeping only categories that contain both female and male observations

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, tidyverse

I'm working with a dataframe where a "job_title" column contains hundreds of titles, and a different column, "gender", specifies whether the person represented by the observation is male or female.

(I'm struggling to figure out) how to drop all rows such that the job title value isn't shared by both a male and a female?

In other words, I want to keep a row if and only if its "job_title" value is recorded for at least one other row which has the other "gender" value. If only males have a specific job title, I want to drop all the rows with that job title; if only females have a job title, I'm looking to drop all rows with that job title too.

Comment: please provide a reproducible output using dput()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, here's a base R solution -

```
df[ave(df$gender, df$job_title, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1, ]
```

With `tidyverse` -

```
df %>%
  group_by(job_title) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(gender) > 1)
```

Comment: The latter of the two options works for my particular case!

Comment: @tres14 both should work but I can test them only if you provide a sample data set.